# How can I make dpkg automatically choose my own virtual package over an already installed one?

Tags: bash, dpkg

I have several packages that provide the same functionality - and in the device 
'there can be only one' at the same time.

I have read about the 'Provides, Conflicts, Replaces' in the debian policy, but I have not found a way (using dpkg with commands/switches) to automatically replace an already installed virtual package without removing it manually first.

My package's control file specifies the following for all the packages in question:

```
Provides: myown-virtual-package
Conflicts: myown-virtual-package
Replaces: myown-virtual-package
```

Here is what I do, It seems to work, but I was wondering if there is a standard way using only dpkg

```
# remove any conflicting virtual packages
for i in /tmp/upgrade_software/*.deb
do
    # find out what package name and what it provides
    provides_line=$(dpkg --info $i | grep "^ Provides: ")
    package_line=$(dpkg --info $i | grep "^ Package: ")
    virt_package=${provides_line##*: }
    this_package=${package_line##*: }

    # skip if it is not a virtual package 
    [ -z "${virt_package}" ] && continue


    # remove any package that provides the same
    otherpackage_line=$(dpkg-query -W -f='${Provides}: ${Package}\n' \
        | grep "${virt_package}:" | grep -v ${this_package})
    if [ -n "${otherpackage_line}" ] ; then
        otherpackage=${otherpackage_line##*: }
        echo "    ------ removing ${otherpackage} because of conflict -------"
        dpkg --purge ${otherpackage}
        echo "    -------------"
    fi
    echo \'$virt_package\' checked for conflicts
done
```

Thanks in advance, jj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dpkg` will not take this kind of automatic conflict resolution measures. For these tasks, there is `apt-get` and `aptitude`. It *may* just work with

```
dpkg -i package.deb ; apt-get -f install
```

The latter command is supposed to resolve the conflicts. If it opts to remove your own package for resolution, you may even want to try

```
dpkg -i package.deb ; apt-get -f install <package>
```

I.e., tell `apt` to install your package (without a `.deb` extension) as it should now be visible to apt.

Comment: Thank You. I must read more on apt, I think. It was my impression that apt was not keen on working without the whole repository machinery, whereas dpkg was the only tool when dealing with raw uploaded deb files.

Comment: Which is generally true. But once you do tell `dpkg` to install a local package, it does appear in the local database of packages, and `apt` must honor this as well.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with dpkg alone, by giving it enough information so that it can perform the operation. The way to prepare dpkg for this is via selections.

In this case you'd tell that removing the old provider is ok, and then when you install the new one dpkg will be able to remove the other package during the upgrade.

Try something like:

```
echo old-provider deinstall | dpkg --set-selections
dpkg -iB new-provider.deb
```

That should in principle do it, and no need for apt-get fixing it up (-f), or for pre purges (possibly with --force options if there are packages depending on the virtuals).

Comment: Thank You - will try it - and update comment accordingly!
I used the other solution with predictable results in a project and it never failed me. Thanks all the same though. Sorry for not checking in for a long time.